# NativeScript + VueJS with PusherChannels

Tags: android, vue.js, nativescript, pusher

I'm new with NS and I'm trying to create my first app on Android. I want to add Pusher so the app runs a function when receiving a message.
However I haven't been able to receive the message in the app. Hope you can guide me through

**NS Plugin:** @nativescript-pusher/channels
**NS Version:** 6.14.4

app.js

```
import { TNSPusher } from '@nativescript-pusher/channels';
TNSPusher.logToConsole = true;
var pusher = new TNSPusher('MY_APP_KEY');
var channel = pusher.subscribe('MY_CHANNEL_NAME');
channel.bind('my-event',
  function(data) {    
    console.log(data.message);    
  }
);
```

Then I go to Debug Console -> Event Creator in Pusher to test.

**Channel:** MY_CHANNEL_NAME
**Event:** my-event
**Data:** "Testing From Pusher"

However I can't see anything in my console. No errors either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you see connection and subscription success messages in the debug console when the app is launched? 
What does you client logging say about connections/subscriptions?

Comment: Well, seems it's a plugin compatibility problem. Waiting for an update or an alternative. Thanks!